# UITabBarController タブ数6以上で表示したい

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

タブを6以上に設定すると「その他」タブが自動的に表示され、5番目以降はまとめられてしまいます。
「その他」タブを表示しないでタブを6つ以上表示するカスタマイズ方法がありましたら、
ご教授ください。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

水平方向がコンパクトな環境では、タブは同時に5つまでしか表示できません。

これは、Appleのヒューマンインターフェイスガイドラインに記述されていますので、無理やりそれ以上表示しても、AppStoreの審査が通らなくなるかと思われます。

iOSヒューマンインターフェイスガイドライン: バー  
https://developer.apple.com/jp/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Bars/Bars.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH12-SW52

Answer (score 1):

先述の通り、Appleが提示しているヒューマンインターフェイスガイドラインでは、多数のタブを追加することは推奨していません。
読むとわかるのですが、下記のような記述があります。

> タブバーにたくさんのタブを詰め込み過ぎることは避ける。タブバーのタブを増やし過ぎると、目的のタブをタップすることが物理的に難しくなります。また、表示するタブを1つ増やすごとに、アプリケーションの複雑さが増します。

また、同ガイドラインではユーザーがタップするボタンの最小サイズを**44px四方**と定めています。
このことからも、あまりオススメはできません。
メニュー項目が多い場合は、FacebookやGoogleが採用している横スライドメニューを考えても良いかもしれません。

因みにですが、
下記のような使い方を提案している人もいます。
[JFATabBarController](https://github.com/vermont42/JFATabBarController/blob/master/README.md)
[ZRScrollableTabBar](https://github.com/raihan/ZRScrollableTabBar/blob/master/README.md)

これらはタブバー部分を横スライドさせることで、多数のタブの配置を可能としています。
(オープンソースなので、ライセンスに従って正しく利用しましょう。)

少しでも参考になれば幸いです。